# How can I copy files from Windows 10 to virtual machine that hosts Linux CentOS

Tags: linux, windows

I have a host OS Windows 10 and I want to copy some files to a virtual machine hosted on the same computer that has installed on it LinuxCentOS
How can I do that ?

Comment: Have you tried to google it? What did you find? What problems with those solutions did you encounter? What virtualization software are you using?

Comment: I've always had good luck mounting the CentOS to a Windows folder share and then I could run commands to copy or whatever just as if the share was a Linux folder. What did you try already and have trouble with specifically?

Comment: This can usually be achieved either using shared folders. VMware for example makes it quite seemless.

Comment: I managed to share the folder but I want to copy from it and I can`t do it with the examples found on google

Answer (score 0):

Most virtualization software allows to set up shared folders that can be accessed from the host and the client. After setting it up in the virtualization software you may have to mount it manually inside the LinuxCentOS.

Another solution, that should work in general, but is less efficient and less secure is to tread host and client like two separate machines in the same network. You can use any network interfaces such as ssh or network file systems such as samba to transfer files between the two. How to reach the client depends on how its virtual network adapter is set up.

Comment: An easy way of copying : Copy the files (As is or compressed) to "the cloud", e.g. Google Drive ... and then copy files from anywhere / from any OS.